# Adobe Air Error #3001: File or directory access denied

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

An application that was built using flash builder using apache flex and adobe air fails on launch and seems to get hung up on the `initialize();` function. It works fine on previous versions of Android and only has a problem with oreo. It seems to trace back to the `SystemManager.as` file at `ApacheFlex4.16/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/SystemManager.as`

Any ideas on what could cause the application not to work in the latest version of android?

Comment: Any progress? I did not know about Oreo issue but you could investigate how other (even native/Java) apps are handling this issue. For example the [Tom-Tom app forums](https://en.discussions.tomtom.com/tomtom-go-mobile-and-navigation-for-android-156/go-mobile-app-just-say-loading-app-1031452) has suggestions like... **(1)** Try running in pilot mode to get past stuck _"Loading"_ screen?? **(2)** Delete app (from older OS install) and also clear your Google Play cache, then Re-install app whilst now running Oreo?? If the two options don't work then investigate further ideas..

Comment: PS: I don't think it's an AIR issue but Adobe might bring out an update. Also `SystemManager.as` seems to load a "preloader animation" library. I don't now if Oreo suspects some security issue or whatever. Does any non-Flex (only AS3 code) testing app work okay?